# How to display the nearest cities using Google API?

Tags: php, google-api

I am developing a travel portal website.
Presently I am working on the destination module.here I need to display the nearest cities based on the places entered.
**for example,If any one enter the name bangalore,The nearest cities around bangalore city should display.**
I am searching for the google api to get the nearest cities around a place.
Can anyone help me to get the best api to display the nearest cities ??

Thanks In advance

Comment: Have a look at Google Places API. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests

Answer (score 0):

This might be an alternative for you,
Another option:

- Download the cities database from http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/
- Add each city as a lat/long -> City mapping to a spatial index such as an R-Tree (some DBs also have the functionality)
- Use nearest-neighbour search to find the closest city for any given point

Advantages:

- Does not depend on aa external server to be available
- Very fast (easily does thousands of lookups per second)

Disadvantages:

- Not automatically up to date
- Requires extra code if you want to distinguish the case where the nearest city is dozens of miles away
- May give weird results near the poles and the international date line (though there aren't any cities in those places anyway